# Does older version such as 3.1.8 Adobe Analysis is ATS(App Transport Security) compliance

Tags: ios, objective-c, adobe-analytics

I am using Adobe Analytics for tagging purpose inside my app, its an old app with library version 3.1.8.

But now Apple is forcing for App Transport Security so how to check weather the library such as Adobe Analytics is ATS compliance and uses SSL in their request.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: there should be a `ADBMobileConfig.json` file included with the AA SDK library. Within it, you should see a `"ssl"` property that should be set to `true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per adobe Website. 
https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/mobile/ios/app_transport_security.html

This page refers to 4.7 and later. We can seamlessly configure to support ATS compliance.

Comment: Link-only answers are not future proof. What happens when someone stumbles upon your answer years after the site you linked to becomes unavailable? Please elaborate your answer with examples, or other information.

Comment: Thanks Soan for the answer so in this case the older version has to be updated to the latest as 4.7 or later are ATS compliance.